# How to generate Roslyn Operator Overloads

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, bitwise-operators, roslyn

I want to leverage Roslyn code generation to generate a Unary Operator and several Binary Operators but I was wondering how I could go about doing that.

Assumptions, `Descriptor` carries with it information such as the underlying `TypeSyntax` for which I am declaring the *operators*.

So far I've postulated something alone these lines:

```
MemberDeclarationSyntax GenerateUnaryOperatorOverload(string methodName, SyntaxKind kind)
{
    const string other = nameof(other);

    var otherSyntax = Parameter(Identifier(other))
            .WithType(Descriptor.Type)
        ;

    var statementSyntax = ParseStatement($"return {otherSyntax.Identifier.ValueText}?.{methodName}();");

    return OperatorDeclaration(Descriptor.Type, Token(kind))
            // Assuming I need to specify Public and Static as part of the overload...
            .WithModifiers(Create(Token(PublicKeyword)).Add(Token(StaticKeyword)))
            .AddParameterListParameters(otherSyntax)
            .WithBody(Block(statementSyntax))
        ;
}
```

As a C# local function... Where `methodName` is the name of the method in a base class that should be called, and `kind` is the operator, such as `BitwiseNotExpression` (?) for the *Ones Complement* operator.

Literally, I want to end up with something like this:

```
public static MyType operator ~(MyType other) => other?.BitwiseNot();
```

If I can land with function a implemented operator overload so much the better. However, this would be an acceptable outcome:

```
public static MyType operator ~(MyType other)
{
    return other?.BitwiseNot();
}
```

A little older coding mannerism, but as generated code would work just as well.

Then, more or less, rinse and repeat for binary operators, i.e. `BitwiseOrExpression`, `BitwiseAndExpression` and `ExclusiveOrExpression` kinds.

Thoughts? Recommendations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found [this little gem](https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/), which, while I wouldn't take the result rote from the generated Roslyn code, it does reveal clues about what can be leveraged based on the kind of code you want to generate. I would use this and read between the lines, i.e. with potentially extraneous `IdentifierName` or `new []{...}`. But it also shows clues like, I really do need to specify bits even as detailed as needing a semi-colon token, i.e. `/* ... */ .WithSemicolonToken(Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken))`. Things of that nature.